# Execute \clearpage before a section only if a certain amount of lines are already filled

Tags: sectioning, conditionals, hooks, lthooks

I use:

```
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\clearpage}
```

to start a new page before a new section. Is there a possibility to only execute this, if more than X percentage of the page is already filled?
So that if the current page only contains a couple lines, `\clearpage` isn't executed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if `\pagetotal` is larger than some fraction of `\pagegoal`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}{\par
  \ifdim\pagetotal>0.5\pagegoal % 50% of pagegoal
    \clearpage
  \fi}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\section{same page}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{next page} % \clearpage here
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

`\pagegoal` is a TeX dimension that holds the vertical size that TeX tries to fill when placing boxes in the main vertical list, and `\pagetotal` is how much of that space is already taken.

Comment: Works perfectly fine! Thanks for the fast help!